# Issues with multiple filters in livequery

Tags: jquery, livequery

I have a selector to which I apply the plugin selectmenu. Works fine however I want to use livequery to deal with hidden elements (if an element is hidden when selectmenu is applied it butchers it).

This works:

```
$('select:visible').filter('[multiple!=multiple]').selectmenu();
```

However I cannot seem to be able to use the same syntax for live query:

```
$('select:visible').filter('[multiple!=multiple]').livequery(function() {
    $(this).selectmenu();
});
```

This does not actually filter elements out that are multiple selects. I have had to do this:

```
$('select:visible').livequery(function() {
    if($(this).attr('multiple') != 'multiple')
        $(this).selectmenu();
});
```

Anyone have an idea why?  I have tried variations such as:

```
$('select:visible:not([multiple=multiple])')...
```

and so on with same issue.

Comment: Have you tried [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with livequery plugin, but this example works: http://jsfiddle.net/p9w49/ without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `[multiple=true]` instead of `[multiple=multiple]` and `[multiple=false]` instead of `[multiple!=multiple]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
$('select:visible:not([multiple])');
```